# How to Calculate Annual Return of A Fund When Contribution is Irregular?

Tags: rate-of-return

I am struggling to calculate the annual return rate for this investment.

Initial Investment on 20-May-2010 $2500

Regular contribution of $250 from 12-July-2010 to 10-10-2013.

Total units accumulated is 28222.29

Unit price on 14-4-2015 is 0.7116.

What is the annual return rate on 14-4-2015 if I am still holding on to this fund?

Thanks for helping me with this.

Cheers,
Ana

Comment: Does "regular contribution" mean monthly? Weekly? Quarterly?

Comment: The Excel function, XIRR is designed for this exact problem...

Comment: Assuming 39 monthly contributions, `XIRR` gives me 14.8%. If I do it manually, I get 13.8%. I must be doing something wrong in one or the other.

Comment: It is monthly contributions Peter. I will use XIRR and see if it is the same as yours. How did you calculate manually?